# Does Boo support DateTime literals?

Tags: boo

Does Boo support DateTime literals?  Something like this:

```
myDate = #2011/1/1#
```

There is no mention about it on the Boo wiki: [http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BOO/Builtin+Literals](https://web.archive.org/web/20120118175551/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BOO/Builtin+Literals). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per documentation, it appears that it doesn't.